# How do I return zero counts in GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count, null

I would like my COUNT and GROUP BY statements to return a zero value

The below is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
,r.Team
,r.Peron_ID
,'Person Status' AS 'VariableType'
, CASE
        WHEN p.STATUS= 'Y' THEN 'Good'
        WHEN p.STATUS = 'N' THEN 'Bad'
        WHEN p.STATUS IS NULL OR p.STATUS NOT IN ('Y','N') THEN 'Invalid'
        END AS VariableA
  ,NULL AS VariableB
into #TC
from    Test r
INNER JOIN Person p ON r.RECORD_NUMBER = p.RECORD_NUMBER

Select 
,t.Team
,t.Person_ID
,VariableType
,variableA
,ISNULL(count(t.Person_ID),0) as Count
from #TC t
Group by t.team, t.Person_ID, variabletype, VariableA
```

For a simple example, in the following table Person1 has a number for each VariableA, however Person2 doesn't have an entry for any of them:

```
+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
| t.Team | t.Person_ID | VariableType  | VariableA | Count |
|--------+-------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
| Team1  | Person1     | Person Status | Good      |     2 |
| Team1  | Person1     | Person Status | Bad       |     3 |
| Team1  | Person1     | Person Status | Invalid   |     2 |
| Team1  | Person2     | Person Status | NULL      | NULL  |
+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
```

How should I go about getting Person2's Good, Bad and Invalid counts showing up as 0?

Please take the above as a sort of pseudo-code, I have paraphrased and simplified my actual code, which is company-specific and relies on lots of casts and cases, so the syntax may not be spot on.

Thanks for the response Ross. Person2 doesn't have his P.STATUS recorded at all. Which is why he's just showing as NULL, I think anyway.

My expected (or just hoped-for) result would like this:

```
+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
| t.Team | t.Person_ID | VariableType  | VariableA | Count |
+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
| Team1  | Person1     | Person Status | Good      |     2 |
| Team1  | Person1     | Person Status | Bad       |     3 |
| Team1  | Person1     | Person Status | Invalid   |     2 |
| Team1  | Person2     | Person Status | Good      |     0 |
| Team1  | Person2     | Person Status | Bad       |     0 |
| Team1  | Person2     | Person Status | Invalid   |     0 |
+--------+-------------+---------------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: P.STATUS has to exist for Person2, there may not be a value, but based on the query above Test r will have an entry for Person2, therefore there will be a status field to check. You might check you case and let everything that is not Y/N fall through in the else. You should include p.STATUS in the result and see what the value is.

Comment: Can you post your expected result? You need to have Person2 and all statuses shown, right? But just with 0 in case this person has no matching value?

Comment: A count(person_id) would not return null, would it? I haven't seen a real world example for it.

Comment: If you also want the counts for those that do not exist, first create a set for all those 3 statuses for each person using a cross join and then using "Person" as the main table do a left join on tests table (Nulls would not be counted - hence 0).

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms175997(v=sql.90)

> COUNT always returns an int data type value. COUNT_BIG always returns
>   a bigint data type value.

Count always not null value

multiple result your status

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (a int, status varchar(255))
INSERT INTO @a VALUES (1, 'Good')

SELECT 
    a.a,
    x.Status, 
    SUM((CASE WHEN a.Status =x.Status THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) Cnt
FROM @a a 
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 'Good' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Bad' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Invalid'
) as x(Status)
GROUP  BY 
    a.a,
    x.Status
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 3 unique values for variableA to show up for each combination of person/team/variabletype, you need to create an inline view with them and then use that in a CROSS JOIN:

```
    CREATE TABLE #Test(
    [RECORD_NUMBER] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Team] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Person_ID] [int] NULL
);

CREATE TABLE #Person(
    [RECORD_NUMBER] [int] NOT NULL,
    [STATUS] [nvarchar](1) NULL
);

SELECT r.Team
,r.Person_ID
,'Person Status' AS 'VariableType'
, CASE
        WHEN p.STATUS= 'Y' THEN 'Good'
        WHEN p.STATUS = 'N' THEN 'Bad'
        WHEN p.STATUS IS NULL and p.RECORD_NUMBER IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN p.STATUS IS NULL OR p.STATUS NOT IN ('Y','N') THEN 'Invalid'
        END AS VariableA
  ,NULL AS VariableB
into #TC
from Test r 
LEFT JOIN Person p ON r.RECORD_NUMBER = p.RECORD_NUMBER;

SELECT 
    t.Team,
    t.Person_ID,
    t.VariableType,
    VarValues.VariableA, 
    SUM((CASE WHEN t.VariableA = VarValues.VariableA THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) Cnt
FROM #TC t
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 'Good' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Bad' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Invalid'
) as VarValues(VariableA)
GROUP  BY 
    t.Team,
    t.Person_ID,
    t.VariableType,
    VarValues.VariableA
ORDER BY t.Person_ID, VarValues.VariableA;

DROP TABLE #TC;
DROP TABLE #Test;
DROP TABLE #Person;
```

Comment: This is looking like it may lead me in the right direction!
How would I go about the above if VariableA isn't a column in the Test table?

Comment: My original answer was both incorrect and untested. Using @Tapakah-Ua 's answer, I have updated my original answer to use your data and provide a complete script you can use to test the functionality.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while, but the cross join was exactly what I needed!